# "Undefined index" error when saving empty array with checkboxes

Tags: php, plugin-development, errors, debug, wp-debug

In my plugin settings page, I have a list of checkboxes that store the value into an array. While the it works as expected, whenever I uncheck all of the checkboxes and save those changes I get the following error:

> **Notice: Undefined index:** *remove_field* in ...\settings-profile.php on line 19

Below is the code in question:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['dsbl_options'] ) && !empty( $_POST['dsbl_options'] ) ) {
    update_option( 'dsbl_remove', $_POST['remove_field'] ); // (Line 19)
}
```

The rest of the source code can be found here: [GitHub](https://github.com/factmaven/disable-blogging/blob/dev/includes/settings-profile.php)

From doing research online for a similar error, I see that the recommendation is to wrap `$_POST['remove_field']` with an `isset`. However, this does not store the values form the checkboxes in the plugin settings.

As mentioned above, this error shows up only when all of the checkboxes are unchecked and saved. It looks like there is an issue when saving an empty value in the array. Although the plugin settings works as expected, I'd like to fix this.

Comment: Add a test for `$_POST['remove_field']` to avoid trying to use it if it's empty.

Comment: May you please elaborate on what you mean by adding a test to `$_POST['remove_fiel‌​d']`?

Comment: You are testing for a value (twice) in `$_POST['dsbl_option']` but you are not testing if `$_POST['remove_field']` has a value before you use it.  If you can post more of your code, I could post a full answer for you.  As it is, I do not know what dsbl_option or 'remove_field' refer to.

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to the source file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing the original snippet from before so I'm not sure of the context anymore.  The undefined index notice you are getting is telling you that `$_POST['remove_fiel‌​d']` does not exist.  If no checkbox in your array was set, the `$_POST` array will not have an index for `'remove_field'`, and you'll see the error.

To prevent this from happening, ensure it exists:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['remove_field'] ) ) {
    // do stuff with the values
}
```

When in an OO context the more frequent solution is to bail out if no value exists so you would reverse your condition:

```
if ( !isset( $_POST['remove_field'] ) ) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: I've re-added the snippet to the question. Is there a way to set a blank value when no checkboxes are selected? I've added the `isset`, however it won't let me uncheck all of the checkboxes.

Comment: That is completely up to you.  You can push any value you wish to represent no checkboxes selected.  An empty/null string, 0, etc would be obvious choices.

Comment: I was able to solve the question between your post and someone else, thank you for helping me solve it +1

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/undefined-index-error-when-saving-empty-array-with-checkboxes?replies=3#post-8758531) (thanks to [bcworkz](https://wordpress.org/support/profile/bcworkz)), I was able to fix the issue by inserting `NULL` if all of the checkboxes are unchecked:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['dsbl_options'] ) && !empty( $_POST['dsbl_options'] ) ) {
    if ( array_key_exists('remove_field', $_POST )) {
        update_option( 'dsbl_remove', $_POST['remove_field'] );
    }
    else { // When all options are unchecked, set array to null
        update_option( 'dsbl_remove', NULL );
    }
}
```